# CSS- background-size: cover stretching height too much

Tags: html, css

In creating a hero image for the top of a page, I am using `background-size:cover` to ensure it takes up the entire width and height of the space.

The problem is that the background image gets stretched way too much vertically. The hero has a max height of 340px, and once the background image reaches that height, I don't want it to continue to be stretched. You can see if the browser window is not too high, you can see most of the image, but as the browser window continues to be stretched vertically, the background image continues to stretch more and more.

How can I make it so if the background image fills the entire width and height of the space, it doesn't need to continue stretching as the browser is resized vertically?

(open attached snippet in a new window and resize your browser vertically)

See also: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJNrVY

EDIT:

Also, notice the following three screenshots. The browser window width is the same in all 3, and the height of the hero container is fixed, so there is no need to continue to stretch the image. I would like to be able to stretch the window vertically, and as long as the image is taking up 100% of the container, there is no need to continue stretching it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```css
.hero {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
  
  height: 340px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero" style="background-image:url(https://webnoo.com/support/wp-content/themes/ihelper/images/page-title.jpg);"></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id exercitationem neque maxime culpa provident ab, vel unde? Iure temporibus suscipit natus numquam? Praesentium illum quos fugiat, quisquam neque illo totam?</p>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me on my side? What browser do you use

Comment: Do you mean stretched out of proportion? I don't see that (on Chrome, Win 10)

Comment: @ovokuro No, its not that it's stretched out of proportion, it's that the taller your browser window is, the more and more and more it's stretched to the point you barely see any of the picture. As long as the width takes up 100%, there's no need to stretch the image any larger than 340px

Comment: @ovokuro The image doesn't need to be stretched proportionate to the window height vertically, it only needs to be stretched to the container height and no further.

Comment: @JROB I'm either not understanding or I'm seeing a different result. When you say "you barely see any of the picture" do you mean because it is zooming out? Or because you are seeing empty space?

Comment: It's not stretching what so ever for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @proevilz Firefox.

Comment: @ovokuro Please note my edit above. I've added screenshots

Comment: @JROB Even though you have added screenshots, I still see no 'stretching'. All I see is the image getting zoomed in a little... still isn't clear what you're referring to.